# ServiceNow Custom Components

Tags: angular, servicenow

I am trying to create a custom UI component in ServiceNow. Setting up project using below command

```
snc ui-component project [--name name_of_app --description 'application description' --scope scope --offline]
```

But it throws me below error -
**Error: unknown flag: --description**

If I remove all non-mandatory values and just execute

```
snc ui-component project [--name name_of_app]
```

It still throws error that - **unknown command "ui-component" for "snc"**

Also, while doing 'snc configure profile refresh' or 'snc configure profile set', it saves profile but also gives warning/error saying -
**This instance does not support dynamic commands. Functionality will be limited.**

Please confirm how can I overcome this error and setup custom UI component project.
I am following below link
https://docs.servicenow.com/bundle/sandiego-application-development/page/build/components/task/setup-component-project.html

Answer (score 0):

I just set this up as well and found that the ui-components have to be installed separately.

```
snc extension add --name ui-component
```

I also had the warning "This instance does not support dynamic commands. Functionality will be limited." I resolved that by installing the plugin on the ServiceNow side called "CLI Metadata" or id:sn_cli_metadata

It will install some additional CLI functionality.

Hope this helps!